# ICU: Which compare API to use?

Tags: unicode, icu

I read the documentation on the different compare APIs that ICU provides, but couldn't quite get the difference between them.

```
int8_t icu::UnicodeString::compare  (const UnicodeString &text  )   const

int8_t icu::UnicodeString::caseCompare  (
        int32_t start, 
        int32_t     length, 
        const UChar * srcChars, 
        int32_t     srcStart, 
        int32_t     srcLength, 
        uint32_t    options 
    )       

virtual EComparisonResult icu::Collator::compare(   
       const UnicodeString &source, 
        const UnicodeString &target 
    )
```

To be able to do case insensitive operations on UTF16 strings, which API fits the bill and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Only one of those three functions performs a case-insensitive comparison, what makes you think the other two do?

Comment: Ok, the documentation of `icu::UnicodeString::compare()` says nothing about case insensitive comparison. `int8_t icu::UnicodeString::caseCompare()` is supposed to do case insensitive comparison, but I have not tried it. I experimented with `icu::Collator::compare()` and found that it can do case insensitive comparison if the collator strength is set appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

from the docs:

- [UnicodeString::compare](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#a250e967fd986956cee7577c656330c02) — this is a bitwise (exact) compare. So, `A` ≠ `a`.
- [UnicodeString::caseCompare](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#a76f9027fbe4aa6f5b863c2a4a7148078) — this is probably what you want to use, but keep reading. `A` = `a` and `ß` = `ss`, etc. You can see [this demo](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/scompare) to play with the comparison.
- Collator - this is for  [locale-sensitive collation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation) which is a different tool. Yes, you can do case sensitive comparison with the right options. But it does more powerful comparisons also, such as `black-bird` = `BlackBird`.

Hope this helps.